# What is the difference between inputting an array into numpy.random.poisson(like input an image) and inputting the value of lambda?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between inputting an array into `numpy.random.poisson` (like input an image) and inputting the value of lambda?

Or to ask: how did `numpy.random.poisson` worked when used to add poisson noise to an image?

Comment: The [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html) explains that a scalar lambda results in a single output value, whereas an array lambda results in an array output the same length as the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so you mean if the input is an array, each value of the output array would be a random draw from the poisson distribution which lambda is the corresponding input value?

Comment: That is exactly right.